# Leage of Legends doesn't launch due to "Can't connect to pvp.net" error

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I used PlayOnLinux to download League of Legends, I managed to get it updated, had to leave it overnight working.

Next day, while logging it, it left errors as "Cannot login in server; try(5)", and things alike, I managed to get it to work, by adding "wininet.dll" thing using WineTricks.

I restarted League of Legends with full hope, but it let me down again.

It does connect to the server, it does check my login data, it does try to log me in. So I see screens like "Connecting to server", "Authentication of data", "Logging in" (note: these are not exact words, but if you used to play League, you know which screens I mean), "Logging In" takes about 20 seconds, then program gives up and prompts me this error:

http://postimg.org/image/i7ldem597/

And this is when I can't Google further. I google League, I googled update issue, I googled connectivity issue, I googled network driver issue, but I **can't** google *this*. I think some of you have been through this and could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this thanks to an answer posted [on the forums](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2057712) (answer by Metaph [on page 2](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2057712&page=2)). Before playing the game, just do:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps"
```

Note that this may have a negative impact on your browsing experience (e.g. slower streaming), so you should turn it back on once you've finished playing, and I strongly discourage setting this up automatically when booting (just in case). The default is `1` for a reason.

**UPDATE**: this was apparently fixed on their end, so this should no longer be needed.

Comment: Tnx mate, i was going crazy with reinstalling and trying every possible not working solution xD

Comment: This may be solved from the server side at some point, but in the meantime, this works flawlessly.

Comment: Yea, I'm RazorFighter90 :), answer provided by Metaph.

Comment: @Anon85902435: I added this precision to the answer if people want to follow the discussion/analysis ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing, apparently it's a server-side issue.

Firstly, using some google Zen skills, I found this: https://downdetector.com/status/league-of-legends.

Also, pinging the login server my Box tried to connect to gives some strange results:

```
% ping 185.40.64.65    
PING 185.40.64.65 (185.40.64.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=4 ttl=245 time=36.5 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=9 ttl=245 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=11 ttl=245 time=36.0 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=12 ttl=245 time=37.1 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=14 ttl=245 time=36.0 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=15 ttl=245 time=37.7 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=16 ttl=245 time=36.9 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=17 ttl=245 time=36.5 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=18 ttl=245 time=36.2 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=19 ttl=245 time=37.2 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=29 ttl=245 time=36.2 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=33 ttl=245 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=36 ttl=245 time=36.3 ms
64 bytes from 185.40.64.65: icmp_seq=37 ttl=245 time=36.5 ms
^C
--- 185.40.64.65 ping statistics ---
38 packets transmitted, 14 received, 63% packet loss, time 37078ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.742/36.523/37.779/0.621 ms
```

Look at dat package loss!

So just wait I suppose :)

Regards, LDer

Comment: Okay :(, may you have guess when it will be over? Tomorrow? A week? A month?

Comment: I've not yet experienced the same, so I don't know.

Comment: As I apparently lack reputation to comment or do an upvote on the now accepted answer: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps` Confirmed working for kernel `3.16.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT` as well! Thanks, BenC!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.. but somehow I got it working. ._.
1. Make sure there's no updates..?
2. Make sure you have LoL installed in your Applications folder
3. Make sure Firewall is turned off (should be turned off)
4. If none of this works - well - repair it.  It worked after I repaired.